# Receiving "Developer error: normalized result is not a number" with cesium version 1.59

Tags: javascript, typescript, cesiumjs

This happens to certain users with different screen resolutions, when they try to pin something on the map.

We've tried changing the screen resolution to 16:10 and it usually works then, but not always.

Has anyone run across this issue?

Comment: This is a bit of a catch-all error, usually it indicates that `NaN` has made its way into the rendering pipeline someplace after objects were incorrectly initialized.  Check your setup and object creation code, and see if you have non-numeric or erroneous values leaking into Cesium from there.